# Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements of a group $G$, then $a^2 \ne b^2$ or $a^3 \ne b^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements of a group $G$, then $a^2 \ne b^2$ or $a^3 \ne b^3$.

Im not really sure how to approach this, any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of a prior question, but good luck finding it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HINT: If $a^2=b^2$ and $a^3=b^3$, then $b^2=a^2=a^3a^{-1}=b^3a^{-1}$. What does this tell you about $ba^{-1}$?

Comment: I don't suppose that the (very belated) downvoter would be so helpful as to identify the problem?

Answer (score 8):

the point is that $2,3$ are coprime so every integer can be expressed in the form $2x + 3y$ by Bezout.

Let $a^2=b^2$ and $a^3=b^3$ then for any $n$ we can pick $x,y$ such that $2x+3y = n$ and then $a^{2x+3y}=b^{2x+3y}$ since $(a^{2})^x(a^{3})^y = (b^{2})^x(b^{3})^y$

Comment: It is enough to take $n=1$ (and $y=1=-x$). This is probably the best answer, since it shows that there is nothing special about $2$ and $3$ ...

Comment: Yes, make $n=1$ and this answer is perfect.

Comment: being able to express any n is equivalent to being able to express all n, since if 1 = ax+by then n = a(nx) + b(ny).

Answer (score 3):

Contrapositively, it is $\rm\: a^2 = b^2,\ a^3 = b^3\:\Rightarrow\: a = b,\:$ with easy proof:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\begin{eqnarray}\rm a^2 = b^2\\ \rm \color{#C00}{a^3 = b^3}\end{eqnarray}$ $\ \Rightarrow$ $\begin{eqnarray} &\rm a^{-2}& = &\rm b^{-2}& \\
\rm a = \color{#C00}{a^3}\!\! &\rm a^{-2}&\rm  = \color{#C00}{b^3}\! &\rm b^{-2}&\rm = b\ \ \ \ \ {\bf QED} \end{eqnarray}$

**Alternatively,** more conceptually, the set $\rm\,S\,$ of integers $\rm\,n\,$ with $\rm\:a^n = b^n\:$ is nonempty ($\rm\,2,3\in S)$ and, furthermore, $\rm\: S\: $ is $ $ *closed under subtraction* $ $  since

$$\rm j, k \in S\ \Rightarrow\ a^j = b^k,\,\ a^{k} = b^{k}\ \Rightarrow\ a^{-k} = b^{-k}\ \Rightarrow\ a^{j-k} = b^{j-k} \Rightarrow\ j-k\in S $$

Hence, by the (subtractive) Euclid algorithm, $\rm\,S\,$ closed under subtraction $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\, S\,$ closed under gcd. Thus since  $\rm\,S\,$ contains two coprime integers, $\rm\,S\,$ contains their gcd $ = 1,\:$ thus $\rm\:\color{#C00}1\in S\:\Rightarrow\: a^{\color{#C00}1} = b^{\color{#C00}1}.$

**Remark** $\ $ If you know about groups or ideals, then the above may be viewed as noticing that the set $\rm\,S\,$ of equalizing exponents, being closed under subtraction, is an additive subgroup of $\:\Bbb Z,\:$ therefore is cyclic, generated by the gcd of its elements. Such cyclic *groups* (and *ideals*) are hidden everywhere in elementary number theory. Great insight is gained by bringing this hidden structure to the fore, esp. explicitly recognizing certain ubiquitous forms of these structures, for example *denominator* ideals and  *order* ideals (annihilators).

Answer (score 2):

What would be happen if $$a^2=b^2,~ \wedge~~ a^3=b^3$$ simultaneously? It would happen $a=b$. A nice contradiction!

Comment: As written, this appears to give no indication of the reasoning on why this is a contradiction. One line such as $$[a^2=b^2]\land [a^3=b^3] \iff [a^{-2} = b^{-2}] \land [ a^{-2}a^3=b^{-2}b^3]\iff [a=b]\quad {\mathrm so}\quad [ a^{-2}a^3=b^{-2}b^3]\Longrightarrow \neg[a=b] $$ would eliminate the assumption that the question is so 'obvious' that no more need be said because obvious is in the eye of the answerer and but not the asker.

Comment: @BarbaraOsofsky: In the time I was adding the answer, Brian's came to page and I felt mine was a dublicate. But, I kept it just to note a small hint. Do you think I should have removed it? Indeed, I added it here as a hint not as a complete answer. Thanks for detailed logical support.